# Using glBufferSubData and glMultiDrawArrays in OpenGL ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, vbo

I am porting a C++ Point and Polygons drawing to Android.Initially it looked straight forward to port the code to java style.I could draw Points using below code.

```
//POINT
public class MyPoint
{

 public float x,y,z;

}
//Points in x,y,z format are parsed and stored here
public static ArrayList<MyPoint> m_vPoints;


public static  float [] fPointVertices ={};//Float array
public static FloatBuffer mPointVerticesFloatBuffer;//Buffer for rendering

int m_drawCount=0;

//Converting to float array
//AND
//Converting to FloatBuffer
public  static void FormatPointDataAsGLBuffer()
{
        fPointVertices=new float[m_vPoints.size()*3];
        int count=0;

        for(int i=0;i<m_vPoints.size();i++)
        {
            fPointVertices[count]=m_vPoints.get(i).x;
            fPointVertices[count+1]=0.0f;
            fPointVertices[count+2]=m_vPoints.get(i).y;
            count=count+3;
        }

        m_drawCount=count;
        //Convert vertices to OpenGL ES compatible format
        mPointVerticesFloatBuffer= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(fPointVertices.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mPointVerticesFloatBuffer.put(fPointVertices).position(0);
}

public void DrawPoints()
{
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mPointVerticesFloatBuffer);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, m_drawCount);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

}
```

I am not yet sure how to draw polygons with a single float array.In the C++ version though,  used glBufferSubData to create the VBO and used single call to glMultiDrawArrays as described in SE query below. 
[Using VBO to draw line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091855/using-vbo-to-draw-line-string)

The polygon related script looks like below

```
//POLYGON

public static ArrayList<MyPolygon> m_vPolygons;
public static class MyPolygon
    {
        public ArrayList<MyPoint> vPointList;
    }


public  static void FormatPolygonDataAsGLBuffer()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<vPolygons.size();i++)
        {

            for(int j=0;j<vPolygons.get(i).vPointList.size();j++)
            {
                fPointVertices[count]=vPolygons.get(i).vPointList.get(i).x;
                fPointVertices[count+1]=0.0f;
                fPointVertices[count+2]=-vPolygons.get(i).vPointList.get(i).y;//Negating since y is outwards from the screen and z is upwards
                count=count+3;
            }

        }   
    }


    public void DrawPolygons()
    {
        //WHAT IS THE RIGHT WAY HERE???
        //glBufferSubData
        //Draw the lines
        //glMultiDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_LINE_LOOP, startIndices,endIndices,nPolygonCount); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glBufferSubData` function still exists so that should still work exactly as before. The `glMultiDrawArrays` function doesn't exist in GLES, so you just need to make multiple separate calls to `glDrawArrays()`, one for each object you want to render.